# Multi-Pass Duplication Identification with Exclusions

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have a customer table with several hundred thousand records.  There are a LOT of duplicates of varying degrees.  I am trying to identify duplicate records with level of possibility of being a duplicate.

My source table has 7 fields and looks like this:
[image: Sample Source Table]

I look for duplicates, and put them into an intermediate table with the level of possibility, table name, and the customer number.
Intermediate Table

```
CREATE TABLE DataCheck (
    id          int             identity(1,1),
    reason      varchar(100)    DEFAULT NULL,
    tableName   varchar(100)    DEFAULT NULL,
    tableID     varchar(100)    DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Here is my code to identify and insert:

```
-- Match on Company, Contact, Address, City, and Phone
-- DUPE
INSERT INTO DataCheck 
    SELECT 'Duplicate','CUSTOMER',tcd.uid
      FROM #tmpCoreData tcd
        INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT
            company, 
            fname,
            lname,
            add1,
            city,
            phone1,
            COUNT(*) AS count
          FROM #tmpCoreData
          WHERE company <> ''
          GROUP BY company, fname, lname, add1, city, phone1
          HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) dl 
        ON dl.company = tcd.company
    ORDER BY tcd.company
```

In this example, it would insert ids 101, 102

The problem is when I perform the next pass:

```
-- Match on Company, Address, City, Phone (Diff Contacts)
-- LIKELY DUPE
INSERT INTO DataCheck 
    SELECT 'Likely Duplicate','CUSTOMER',tcd.uid
      FROM #tmpCoreData tcd
        INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT
            company, 
            add1,
            city,
            phone1,
            COUNT(*) AS count
          FROM #tmpCoreData
          WHERE company <> ''
          GROUP BY company, add1, city, phone1
          HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) dl 
        ON dl.company = tcd.company
    ORDER BY tcd.companyc
```

This pass would then insert, 101, 102 & 103.
The next pass drops the phone so it would insert 101, 102, 103, 104
The next pass would look for company only which would insert all 5.

I now have 14 entries into my intermediate table for 5 records.

How can I add an exclusion so the 2nd pass groups on the same Company, Address, City, Phone but DIFFERENT fname and lname.  Then it should only insert 101 and 103

I considered adding a NOT IN (SELECT tableID FROM DataCheck) to ensure IDs aren't added multiple times, but on the 3rd of 4th pass it may find a duplicate and entered 700 records after the row it's a duplicate of, so you lose the context of it's a dupe of.

My output uses:

```
SELECT 
    dc.reason,
    dc.tableName,
    tcd.*
  FROM DataCheck dc
  INNER JOIN #tmpCoreData tcd
    ON tcd.uid = dc.tableID
ORDER BY dc.id
```

And looks something like this, which is a bit confusing:
[image: Output Table]

Comment: `but on the 3rd of 4th pass it may find a duplicate and entered 700 records after the row it's a duplicate of, so you lose the context of it's a dupe of.`  You're misunderstanding something important about SQL - there is no such thing as "order" in a table (in the fashion you want).  That the rows are being inserted in this fashion is an accident of optimization, and absolutely cannot be relied upon.  The correct thing to do is to also store a reference to the "original" customer.  Answer incoming.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to challenge your perception of your issue, and instead propose that you calculate a simple "confidence score", which will also help you vastly simplify your results table:

```sql
WITH FirstCompany AS (SELECT custNo, company, fname, lname, add1, city, phone1
                      FROM(SELECT custNo, company, fname, lname, add1, city, phone1, 
                                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY company ORDER BY custNo) AS ordering
                           FROM CoreData) FC
                      WHERE ordering = 1)

SELECT RankMapping.description, Duplicate.custNo, Duplicate.company, Duplicate.fname, Duplicate.lname, Duplicate.add1, Duplicate.city, Duplicate.phone1
FROM (SELECT FirstCompany.custNo AS originalCustNo, Duplicate.*, 
             CASE WHEN FirstCompany.custNo = Duplicate.custNo THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
             + CASE WHEN FirstCompany.fname = Duplicate.fname AND FirstCompany.lname = Duplicate.lname THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
             + CASE WHEN FirstCompany.add1 = Duplicate.add1  AND FirstCompany.city = Duplicate.city THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
             + CASE WHEN FirstCompany.phone1 = Duplicate.phone1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
             AS ranking
      FROM FirstCompany
      JOIN CoreData Duplicate
        ON Duplicate.custNo >= FirstCompany.custNo
           AND Duplicate.company = FirstCompany.company) Duplicate
JOIN (VALUES (4, 'original'),
             (3, 'duplicate'),
             (2, 'likely dupe'),
             (1, 'possible dupe'),
             (0, 'not likely dupe')) RankMapping(score, description)
 ON RankMapping.score = Duplicate.ranking
ORDER BY Duplicate.originalCustNo, Duplicate.ranking DESC
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/08869/7/0)</kbd>

... which generates results that look like this:

```
| description     | custNo | company  | fname   | lname  | add1         | city         | phone1     |
|-----------------|--------|----------|---------|--------|--------------|--------------|------------|
| original        | 101    | ACME INC | JOHN    | DOE    | 123 ACME ST  | LOONEY HILLS | 1231234567 |
| duplicate       | 102    | ACME INC | JOHN    | DOE    | 123 ACME ST  | LOONEY HILLS | 1231234567 |
| likely dupe     | 103    | ACME INC | JANE    | SMITH  | 123 ACME ST  | LOONEY HILLS | 1231234567 |
| possible dupe   | 104    | ACME INC | BOB     | DOLE   | 123 ACME ST  | LOONEY HILLS | 4564567890 |
| not likely dupe | 105    | ACME INC | JESSICA | RABBIT | 456 ROGER LN | WARNER       | 4564567890 |
```

This code baselessly assumes that the smallest `custNo` is the "original", and assumes matches will be equivalent to solely that one, but it's completely possible to get other matches as well (just unnest the subquery in the CTE, and remove the row number).

Comment: Thanks!  I'm going to have to sit with it and pull it apart so I can understand it well.  I don't like using code I don't understand :D  I'll need to put it all in a table so I can run reports on it and I had some issues doing that with CTE.

Comment: This is great.  Understand it pretty well now.  I actually added to it to make the confidence score work a bit better for me.

Comment: The one issue I see is that I have a bunch of entries without Company (ie Company = ''), and none of those are processed.  I also have a bunch missing a phone number, so that's throwing it off, I have 'original's marked a 'duplicate' because it was calculated incorrectly.